# Is it possible to defeat the boss *spoiler* after catching up to the prince or is it a forced defeat?

Tags: prince-of-persia-the-lost-crown

I don't think I've gotten very far into the game yet, just chasing after the prince and just caught up to him. Then things happen and I'm in a boss fight against:

> Vahram

Is it possible to win this fight at this point in the game or is it a forced defeat? If so, any rewards?

I managed to get the boss down to ~10% health but eventually got caught in one of their attacks and I died. But apparently having died here progressed the story.

I could have probably defeated the boss and am considering retrying. But would be nice to know if someone already has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look like the boss can be defeated, that is, be taken down to 0 health. But even defeating them will still result in the same outcome, the same events that occurred when I was defeated.

Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEp-qiJ7Qqs) of that fight and dealing the final blow.